# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have been able to access a resource from different origin in IE with Microsoft.XMLHTTP , so I assume that proper response headers are coming from the other server.
but when I try to access the same resouce using XMLHttpRequest in chrome it fails with below error

```
GET http://example1.com/appName/app/home.aspx?Option=2&S=1&D=1&C=US&C=1391 
(anonymous function) @ VM514:2
InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM369:875
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM369:808
InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM369:664

VM514:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
Failed to load 'http://example1.com/appName/app/home.aspx?Option=2&S=1&D=1&C=US&C=1391'
```

Now I don't know what is the issue I am using chrome V47.x

Any Idea???

Comment: When you say 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', do you mean you are using ActiveX? What IE versions are you targeting?

Comment: It really sounds like you are using ActiveX's Ajax implementation. It has been a long time since I've used this, but it follows your system's zone policy settings to decide if it will allow outgoing Ajax requests or not. Most modern developers use `XMLHttpRequest` only for managing requests ONLY (fallbacks only for truly ancient browsers). For this, the *server* must be configured for Cross-Domain requests. The best write up on this is on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the response, but I am 111% sure :) that I am using XMLHttpRequest for chrome and for IE i am using ActiveX,
and in IE the Cross-Origin Domain access is working without any issues.
but in chrome it fails.

Comment: That's my point. Only use ActiveX only if you a strong reason to. It inherits a bunch of local system settings that your users won't have, so you can never be sure that your users will see what you see. IE has basic support for XMLHttpRequest since IE7, so using ActiveX is pretty pointless today. Once you start using it for all platforms, you'll see the same CORS problem consistently. If you can, open the Developers Tab and inspect the network requests. See what requests are leaving the browser (e.g. an `OPTIONS` request). That will help track down the problem.

Comment: Can you post some code. Your Chrome error is a bit odd. Is it in a pop-up window or are you using a framework?

Comment: getUrl = window.location;
baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
if (window.chrome !== undefined) {
objHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (baseUrl.indexOf('localhost') != -1) {
objHTTP.open("GET", baseUrl + '/' + strTemp, false);
} else {
objHTTP.open("GET", baseUrl + '/applications/' + strTemp, false);
}
} else {
objHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
objHTTP.open('GET', baseUrl + '/' + strTemp, false);
}
objHTTP.send();

Andrew this is the code which is failing in chrome but working in IE 11.
Not allowed to remove Existing Code. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101973/discussion-between-pratik-and-andrew).